# Symfony2 many to many with unique table

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using Symfony2.0.18/Doctrine to implement a function.

There are two tables "student" and "teacher", in which their usernames must be unique. 
They are also many-to-many relationship.
What i want to do is to enable the students to add/remove teachers.
If the teacher exists already, just inserting an entry in relationtable "student_2_teacher".

I have created Entity for both "teacher" and "student", and a "StudentController.php".
It works fine if the teacher doesn't exit with $student->addTeacher($teacher);
But if the teacher exists, i got always the unique error.

PS:  how can i make sure the relation between teacher and student is saved?

Can someone give me some advice?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: add some code to your question, like how you defined relations in your entity and forms

Comment: check out this cookbook tutorial, http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: Thank you, i will check out the tutorial. It seems a little bit complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

"form collections" is unnecessary.
There are 2 things, which have to be considered.

1. because teacher username is unique, it must be checked at first. If teacher username exists already, just add the relationship with "addTeacher($teacherOld)", if not, using "addTeacher($teacher)"
2. save relationship between teacher and student with $student->addTeacher($teacher);

`public function addAction(Request $request) {
    $student = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getstudent();`

```
$teacher = new teacher();
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($teacher)
    ->add('teacherUsername', 'text')
    ->getForm();

if($request->getMethod() == 'POST')  {
    $form->bindRequest($request);
    if($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $teacherUsername = $form->get('teacherUsername')->getData();

        // check teacherUsername exist?
        $teacherOld = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('PSEMainBundle:teacher')->findOneByTeacherUsername($teacherUsername);
        if ($teacherOld) {
            $student->addTeacher($teacherOld);
        } else {
            $teacher->setTeacherUsername($teacherUsername);
            $student->addTeacher($teacher);
        }

        // add relations
        $em->persist($student);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_teacher'));
    }
}

return $this->render('PSEMainBundle:teacher:add.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for your information, you should always handle owning and inverse side of relations on your own. The logic is fairly simple, and I extracted it from the gist at https://gist.github.com/Ocramius/3121916 :

```
public function addTeacher(Teacher $teacher)
{
    if ($this->teachers->contains($teacher)) {
        return;
    }

    $this->teachers->add($teacher);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to check if teacher exists in student entity.

In your Student Entity class method addTeacher:

```
public function addTeacher($teacher)
{
    if (!in_array($teacher, $this->teachers->toArray())) {
        $this->teachers[] = $teacher;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. In this way, i will get only the teachers, which alreay associated to the student, not all teachers in the table.

Comment: And the relationship between teacher and student will not be saved either.